# How to find out which Win API functions are called from a compiled c/c++ dll

Tags: c++, api, winapi, dll

I have a compiled C/C++ Dll.

I would like to know which external API function is called by this Dll.

Do you know any tools which can provide these informations.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see API imports of a DLL. Of course that doesn't tell you if the DLL does dynamic loading, or COM usage.

Next to that you could use the much heavier [logexts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560170(VS.85).aspx) extension to windbg, which will dump all API calls at runtime.

Comment: Dependency Walker will also tell you about the dynamically loaded imports. But for that to work, you need to run an application that uses the DLL and invokes the propper code paths that do the loading.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `dumpbin` utility with the `/imports` command-line option. There's also a `depends.exe` utility which as a GUI.

Beware that these won't tell you about functions which you link to use `GetProcAddress`, nor about interfaces which you access via COM.

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Walker (depends.exe) will be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

What does mean by external API(are you considering WINAPI as an external API ?).
if windows API is not an external API then we can use to DumpBin.exe to display all external api used in the binary.
if you want to see the dependent dll/exe of an executable then you can use Depend.exe.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, dependency walker only shows functions that are called directly, not the ones that are called via function pointers. If you want to find **all** the APIs that are called, log all the calls to GetProcAddress.

Answer (score 0):

Ida Pro, The universally accepted disassembler. It has seperate tab for Import and Export Function.It has several other uses in the field of reverse engineering.